# DropDownList - selected value shown in edit form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have MVC3 website with edit form. On this form there is DropDownList that shows list of values that can be chosen. I want it to be set at previously selected value(on create form). This value is  in Model.Status. I thought that this code would work:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Status",
           new SelectList(ViewBag.Status as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Id", "Status", Model.Status))
```

But the DropDownList is always set on first value from the list. I have checked - the correct value is in `Model.Status`. 
Value of `Model.Status` is an id of status from list. `ViewBag.Status` is a list with id and string description - Status.

How to make it show the right value?
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I think you should override the Equal method for the type "Status", if the Model.Status is not one of the elements of ViewBag.Status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [this bug](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/4932)

Avoid to use same name of `DropDownList`and `SelectList`.

Comment: You are right - that was the problem. I have already tried a lot of different solutions but I didn't even thought that this is a problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedItemId,
                     new SelectList(ViewBag.Status as System.Collections.IEnumerable,"Id",
                     "Status"),"Select Item")
```

But If i am writing this code, i would get rid of the `ViewBag` and change that to use another strongly typed object

```
public class YourMainViewModel
{
  public int ID { set;get;}

  public int SelectedItemId { set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<Item> Items();
  //other properties
}

public class Item
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string Status { set;get;}
}
```

Instead of sending the collection in `Viewbag`, i would use my new model properties now

```
public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
{
  var user=myRepositary.GetUser(id);
  user.Items=myRepositary.GetAllItems();
  user.SelectedItemId=5; // replace with the value from your database here,
}
```

Now in my View which is strongly typed to `YourMainViewModel`, I will write this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedItemId,
                     new SelectList(Model.Items,"Id",
                     "Status"),"Select Item")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that you can modify and use in your scenario.  I have an Edit view, on this view are a list of banks in a dropdown, and the bank that is associated with this application is already pre-selected in the list.

My view:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel
```

My banks dropdown:

```
<td><b>Bank:</b></td>
<td>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(
          x => x.BankId,
          new SelectList(Model.Banks, "Id", "Name", Model.BankId),
          "-- Select --"
     )
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.BankId)
</td>
```

My MyViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     // Partial class

     public int BankId { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
}
```

My Edit action method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     // Get the required application
     GrantApplication application = grantApplicationService.FindById(id);

     // Mapping
     MyViewModel viewModel = (MyViewModel)
          grantApplicationMapper.Map(
          application,
          typeof(GrantApplication),
          typeof(MyViewModel)
     );

     // BankId comes from my table.  This is the unique identifier for the bank that was selected when the application was added

     // Get all the banks
     viewModel.Banks = bankService.FindAll().Where(x => x.IsActive);

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

My bank class:

```
public class Bank
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Doing it this way will have a selected value in your dropdown after the form has loaded.

I hope this helps :)